# original windows 7 became evaluation copy after SP1 installation

Tags: windows-7, windows, service-pack

my licensed windows 7 professional (*64bit*) became *evaluation copy* after service pack 1 RC installation and will expire. is there a way to fix this besides re-installation of the OS?

Comment: Are you sure it was not SP1 RC?

Comment: yes it was SP1 RC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to attempt to activate your "evaluation" copy.  When you do, it sounds like the activation will fail.  At this point it should give you a phone number you can use to contact Microsoft, and their support *should* be able to fix this for you.

Comment: +1.  Just try to reactivate.  Even if you have to call up, I'm sure they won't give you much hassle.

Comment: i removed SP1 RC completely. had some issues with ie8.

Answer (score 3):

You could try re-entering your valid install key:

1. Right Click on My Computer and Select Properties.
2. Wait for activation details to get populated.
3. Click on Change Product key link (after activation details are populated).
4. Enter your Product Key and click on next to activate.